# Right click and left click menu bar app

Tags: objective-c, menu, menubar, right-click

I have this menu bar app where that is meant to preform an action when it is left click and shows the menu when it is right click. The only thing is I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help me?
This is the code I have for enabling the menu bar app:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [_aboutWindow orderOut:nil];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{

    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"icon" ofType:@"png"]];
    statusHighlightImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"hicon" ofType:@"png"]];

    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:statusHighlightImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

-(void)dealloc{

    [statusImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard for us to answer if you say 'I want this' because the answer is too broad. Instead, describe the problem you're currently having or what is it that is not working.

Comment: I am asking how to do it because I don't know how.